# SAP GUI Script: Set focus on Input Field in order to SendKeys

Tags: user-interface, vbscript, scripting, edit, sap-gui

In my SAP GUI VBS Script, I want to paste the Clipboard to an Input Field. I use `WshShell.SendKeys "^V"`, but it does not do anything and I suspect this because the Input Field has no focus.

So far my best guess was to "write" empty text into the field and then set the caret position to 0 and hope that this shifts focus to the field, but it does not help:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-MATNR").text = ""
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-MATNR").caretPosition = 0
```

I have not found any methods for the `session` object, I hoped to find anything like `session.setFocus` or similar.

Is there a way to set focus on an Input Field?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about, for example, with

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-MATNR").setfocus

Regards,
ScriptMan

Comment: Seems to work, now I have to find out why my `WshShell.SendKeys "^V"` does not paste.

Comment: `^V` (`CTRL + V` shortcut) is equivalent to `V78` virtual key. See more about virtual keys at [this](https://experience.sap.com/files/guidelines/References/nv_fkeys_ref2_e.htm) link.